# NetSuite SuiteScript Client Side drop down validation

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a custom form where, in a subtab, I have a dropdown that I need to find out the selected value on the client side after the user selects to perform some validation. I created the script and tied it to the on change event of the dropdown. I cannot seem to find the code to get the selected value on the client side. I have found code to read the value on the server side from a submit event. I need this on the client side on change. I am going to use the ID to look up a record and check a value on that record and if applicable popup a warning to the user. Either SS1 or SS2 is good, whatever would be better I have both available. Any help with this would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the nlapiGetFieldValue, did not do the trick, what did was the following

```
function ValidateField( type, field, linenum ) {
    if ( field === 'recordid' ) {
        var vendorid = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue(type,field,linenum);
        var vendorRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('vendor',vendorid);

    }

    return true;
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `nlapiGetFieldValue()` is used to retrieve body level fields, and `nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue` is for line level fields. You should remove the third parameter (linenum) from the argument list, and also best to test the sublist as well - `if (name === 'sublistid' && field === 'recordid')`

Answer (score 0):

In a client script, you can use `nlapiGetFieldValue()` to retrieve the results.

```
function fieldchanged(type, name, linenum) {
    if(name == 'dropdownid') {
        var value = nlapiGetFieldValue('dropdownid');
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this and I get back a null value, I should be using the field id as the dropdown id correct? thanks for your help